# Moodle | Getting course data moodle

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I have a custom page `information.php` with a link in every course in `Moodle`, where is printed the summary of every course.

To show the course name I have in `information.php`

```
global $DB, $COURSE;   

$course = $COURSE->fullname;
```

The problem is, that it prints *only* the information from the first `course id`:

```
Coursename1
```

and not according to the current course, where I clicked on the link.

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to pass the course id to your information page.

In the original page display the link:

```
$url = new moodle_url('\local\yourplugin\information.php', array('id' => $course->id));
echo html_writer::link($url, get_string('informationlink', 'local_yourplugin'));
```

Then in your information.php page:

```
$courseid = required_param('id', PARAM_INT);

// Use get_course() for performance.
$course = get_course($courseid);

// Use require_login($course) to test if the user can see this course.
require_login($course);
```

Comment: Hi Russell, it works! In this case I am using JS to place the Link on the page. ` if($('#page-course-view-customtopics .bluebar p')) {
        $('#page-course-view-customtopics #section-0 .summary').append('<img src="http://localhost/moodle1/theme/image.php/customtopics/core/1456140198/f/pdf-24" height="24" width="24"><button class="information">informations</button>');
    }` How to pass here the `course id` to the information page? Thanks in advance!